# Geopy distance import not working. ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'geopy'

Tags: python, import, module, geopy

I am working on a project and a sub task is to find the distance between two points. However, the geopy module isn't functioning.

I have pip installed the module: `pip install geopy`. However, when I run my program I get an error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/name/Documents/Krems/Programming/Assignment 3/code/code.py", line 3, in <module>
    from geopy.distance import geodesic
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'geopy'
```

The import I use is `import geopy.distance`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick explain so you can understand.

```
from geopy.distance import geodesic
```

In this line you are asking python to import 'geodesic' from geopy.distance, but it seems like you didn't install geopy.
Try using `pip3 install geopy` and tell me if it works.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I tried what you outlined, when I install the module using pip3 I get this message:

`Requirement already satisfied: geopy in ./venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages (2.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: geographiclib<3,>=1.52 in ./venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from geopy) (2.0)`

Additionally I still get the `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'geopy'`

Comment: then try this 'from geopy import geodesic' if this doesn't work either tell me. i also tried  the code you posted on the question and it works. can you tell me what version of python you are using?

Comment: I did `python --version` and got `Python 2.7.18` I subsequently installed the newest version of python `brew install python` now when I enter `python3 --version` I get `Python 3.10.4` How do i know which version is running on my computer because `python --version` still yields `Python 2.7.18`

Comment: To check what python version the script is running I ran this line of code. `import sys      
print(f'Your Python version is {sys.version}')` This returned `Your Python version is 3.9.12 (main, Apr  5 2022, 01:53:17)`